# jQuery Mobile data-filter, in case of no result

Tags: jquery, search, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm currently exploring jQuery Mobile to develop a mobile version of a dashboard with ordertracking information. And what the plan is, is to use a simple unordered list with all orders, and people can click on the link they want to know more about.
Because this list can become quite large, it is nice to have a filter ability which it's easy to do with jQuery Mobile.

Just something like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

`data-filter="true"` takes care of displaying a searchbar and it actually works pretty nice.

But my only problem is, when nothing is found, it just displays nothing, and I would like there to be a bit of text saying something like "Sorry, no orders where found."

Does anybody know if this is possible with jQuery Mobile, or is it something that has to be coded from scratch?

Comment: Check if `$('ul[data-role="listview"] > li').size() < 1` maybe? If there is no built-in function that is

Comment: @Johan, Thanks, I've been thinking about something like that, but first wanted to be sure no build-in function exists. Cause you can get the searchbar up with one data attribute, you can change the placeholder with one attribute, so I figured changing the 'no-result-case' would also not be a problem.

Comment: Ok, sound like it should exists something similar, i guess you will have to wait and see if someone who knows it better than me answers. At least you have a backup plan now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//wait to do event binding until the page is being initialized
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function () {

    //cache the list-view element for later use
    var $listview = $(this).find('[data-role="listview"]');

    //delegate event binding since the search widget is added dynamically
    //bind to the `keyup` event so we can check the value of the input after the user types
    $(this).delegate('input[data-type="search"]', 'keyup', function () {

        //check to see if there are any visible list-items that are not the `#no-results` element
        if ($listview.children(':visible').not('#no-results').length === 0) {

            //if none are found then fadeIn the `#no-results` element
            $('#no-results').fadeIn(500);
        } else {

            //if results are found then fadeOut the `#no-results` element which has no effect if it's already hidden
            $('#no-results').fadeOut(250);
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu4r/1/

Comment: Okay, seems to work quite nice. So there's no real build in option for this... hmm, okay. Btw, do you notice that once you get to a point where no results are found, the next letter you typ the `#no-results` element will fadeOut again, next letter it fadeIn again, etc.

Comment: @Crinsane I thought that using `.not(this)` would omit the `#no-results` element from the selection but I had to change it to `.not('#no-results')`. I **updated** my answer, here is the new demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu4r/1/

Comment: Although I was hoping I would fine a build in function, I like this piece of code too, so thank you very much!

Comment: I was watching this post. @Jasper I did find that when we click the **x** in the search bar the "no results" id would comeback in the listview. Is there a way to get around this? 1st I thought I should read more about the working principle of the **x** button in jQM-`data-filters` but then I found the other way which is: we can also do page `refresh` when we click the **x**, need some insight..

Comment: @uDaY If you set a timeout to hide the `#no-results` element you can hide it just after the animation to show it starts. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu4r/2/

Comment: @uDaY i've added the modification. please check it. http://jsfiddle.net/6Vu4r/39/

Answer (score 3):

Thank you

I'm using this code with an extension. I don't want to write each time this #no-result li.

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageinit', function() {

var $listview = $(this).find('[data-role="listview"]');
$listview.append('<li id="no-results" style="display:none;">[No results found]</li>');
$listview.listview('refresh');
$(this).delegate('input[data-type="search"]', 'keyup', function() {
    if ($listview.children(':visible').not('#no-results').length === 0) {
        $('#no-results').fadeIn(500);
    } else {
        $('#no-results').fadeOut(250);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use @Jasper's code on a list with auto-dividers you might find that the hidden "no results" element stills creates a divider. To avoid that I used this code:

```
if ($listview.children(':visible').not('#no-results').length === 0) {

        // if none are found then fadeIn the `#no-results` element
        $('#no-results').fadeIn(500);

    } else {

        // if results are found then fadeOut the `#no-results` element which
        // has no effect if it's already hidden
        $('#no-results').fadeOut(250);
        $listview.children('.ui-li-divider:visible').not('#no-results').each(function()             {
            if($(this).next("#no-results").length > 0)
                $(this).hide();
        });
    }
```

If anyone has a better solution please share.